# RF receiver to detect unknown drone RC links

Tags: rf, remote-control, drone

I am currently developing anti drone system as a project. Therefore,I am in need to make a RF receiver /Sensor , which can detect RC links(Drone-controller RC link) at multiple frequencies(488 MHz/2.4GHz). Can any one give me idea, about where i can start from? Is USRP the way to go or should i look at microcontrollers like SMT,Arduino?
The idea per say, is that i am developing a RC link receiver that detects drones in the vicinity by snooping on the RC control links. Therefore detecting and identifying the drone.
Thank you

Comment: Which side are you on?

Comment: Neither, Just working on the assigned project.

Comment: That is really difficult. Every manufacturer is going to use their own control protocol, and serious drones are going to use encrypted spread spectrum control.

Comment: 2.4GHz is used by Wi-fi, Bluetooth, Zigbee and all sorts of other stuff, even microwave cookers. Identifying drone traffic among that lot is going to be extremely difficult.

Comment: @Finbarr Especially since some drones are controlled via WiFi...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with this list: 
[List of SDR's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software-defined_radios)
Pick one you like and that recieves in the range of the drones your interested in listening in on.

That will get you started on just listening in on the frequency bands. If you want to decode the information being sent back you'll have to reverse engineer the radios on each drone you want to monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Well for the RF side you want a VHF to low microwave coverage receiver, USRP/HackRF 1/Whatever, but your real challenge is going to be signal classification.

A Consumer drone MIGHT use a single frequency control channel and might (but I really would not count on it) use simple minded video links (Which can be detected semi reliably by looking for the sync pulses), but anything done well will be using spread spectrum for both, and wifi for video is not untypical which is hard to tell apart from netflix when all you have is the RF.

Now you **might** for certain drones be able to find a footprint by thinking more about RFI then control links and looking for such things as LO leakage, also by looking for RF envelope modulation by the power supply nose from the ESCs, these sort of side channels may well be a better target then the radios themselves, as a non drone RF user is not likely going to have the level of noise from the ESCs at typical motor drive frequencys.

Then, when you have identified a **possible** drone (And what p value is sufficient certainty?), what you going to do about it? Jamming is pretty much a no-go, for legal reasons, and while spinning up the goalkeeper for point defence is tempting it also causes paperwork.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Dan. The project is of course only a prototype.While i am currently working on a robust algorithm for the signal classification,but What if all the drones that are in the vicinity are emitting some kind of UID/Electronic ID in their RF communication(Implemented by the manufacturer). Will it help the cause? The idea is to Detect and identify, rather than to eliminate.

Comment: Depends on what that ID is, if it is for example buried in telemetry data, encrypted then modulated onto some sort of spread spectrum link you will have a lot of trouble even identifying that there is a transmitter there unless it is very close, and even then it just looks like noise unless you know the spreading sequence. On the other hand if the thing has a radio talking a defined protocol (Serial number, GPS position and altitude, heading and speed), sort of like maritime AIS, then the drone bit ceases to be interesting you just decode the data, but that is not the interesting case.